# the array Initialize in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int arr[10] = {};
    for(auto element : arr)
    {
        cout<<element<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

if i write `int arr[10] = {}`, the elements in `arr` are all `0`. but if i just wrtie `int arr[10]`, the elements in `arr` are random.
So i am confused about `int arr[10] = {}`, i just declare a array `int arr[10]`, but i don't give it any value, just a `{}`.

Comment: This is just a syntactic sugar, in many situations you need to create array of integers initialized with zeros, Imagine that array size is `1000` instead, aside that sytax only way is to loop thru array and assign `0` to each element manually. Read more about arrays [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/)

Comment: Now that you have an answer, for kicks, remove the `=`  (but keep the `{}`) and try it again. `int arr[10]{};`

Comment: @WhozCraig the result is `0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 `, the `=` is maybe useless, what's the reason?

Comment: That would spoil the fun. Do some hunting on SO when you have some spare time and search for more related C++ questions on different *initialization methods*. And thanks for trying it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if i write int arr[10] = {}, the elements in arr are all 0.

That is just how the syntax of the language works. In your case the array will be zero initialized.

> but if i just wrtie int arr[10], the elements in arr are random.

In your case array elements are not initialized. You should not read values of variables which are not initialized; otherwise you will trigger undefined behavior.

Comment: actually `int arr[10] = {};` will *value-initialize*.  `int arr[10];` is *default-initialize* which means to do nothing for int. (See [dcl.init/7])

Comment: Does it only work for basic type(int, float, dobule)? if i define a custom class `Person`, does `Person arr[10] = {}` work?

Comment: @BlackMamba In that case instance of your object will be default initialized - whatever default initialization means for your class, AFAIK.

Comment: @Giorgi To be more precise, they will also be *value initialized*. This can make a difference in some cases.

Comment: @BlackMamba if `Person` has a constructor then *default-initialize* means to call that constructor to initialize a `Person`

Answer (score 2):

according to cpp reference website (http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization) this is how to initialize all array elements to zero:

> int a[3] = {}; // invalid C but valid C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array

Answer (score 0):

`int arr[10];` 
is not initializing anything, it's allocating memory blocks the size of an `int` and you are getting what ever is in that memory.

`int arr[10] = {};`
is initializing all the `int` blocks to null/0

Comment: That is true for builtin types like int, but the difference between default and value initialized for types with constructors is more complex.

Comment: @MartinBonner but he is using an int array in the example and asking why he is getting all 0 or random data. Am I missing something? I get what you are saying but don't think it applies to the question. Would `object arr[10] = {}` just use the default constructor of that objects?

Comment: If there is a default constructor, `object arr[10] = {};` and `object arr[10];` will both call it.  If it's a POD type then each object will be zero initialized in the first case and left indeterminate in the second case.

Comment: initializing int blocks to null?